# Python Regex : find next 5 alphabets

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like `"SW: C000032345RE"`. I am trying to extract next 10 alphabets.

So the answer should be like `"C000032345RE"`. I am trying to achieve it with two different methods

Fist is next 10 alphabets after SW: or the alphabets between SW: and RE. I am using following script

```
import re 
sub = "SW: C000032345RE"
a= re.search("^SW: (\w)", sub)
a.group(0)
```

of course its not showing me desired results. Every help is important!

Comment: try `"SW:\s*(\w+)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s*` means zero or more whitespaces and `\w{10}` means 10 single word characters:

```
import re 
sub = "SW: C000032345RE"
a = re.search("^SW:\s*(\w{10})", sub)
print (a.group(1))
C000032345
```

Comment: For every problem, you have solution in `pandas`, LOL. You are a master in `pandas`.

Comment: There was tag pandas before, sorry ;)

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, I was specifically looking for Regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

Solution without using `regex`,

```
In [84]: val = sub.find('SW: ')+len('SW: ')
In [85]: sub[val:val+10]
Out[85]: 'C000032345'
```

Comment: Thank Rahul for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for a single word character (`\w`) when you should be searching for 10 of them (`\w{10}`). You also want `group(1)` for the contents of the parentheses, not `group(0)` which is the whole match.

```
import re 
sub = "SW: C000032345RE"
a = re.search("^SW: (\w{10})", sub)
a.group(1)
```

You should probably also be checking `a` before calling methods on it, as the regex might not have matched! E.g.

```
>>> sub = "SW: C00003..."
>>> a = re.search("^SW: (\w{10})", sub)
>>> a.group(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `SW:` should be a positive lookbehind assertion(`?<=`) so that you capture only the required data if the preceded by the match!

```
>>> import re 
>>> sub = "SW: C000032345RE"
>>> a = re.search("(?<=SW: )\w{10}", sub)
>>> a.group(0)
'C000032345'
```

Comment: `(?!...)` isn't a non-capturing group. Also a non capturing group doesn't prevent parts of the string to be returned in the whole match.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry about that! Edited the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should use simple string slicing like

```
>>> sub = "SW: C000032345RE"
>>> sub[-12:]
'C000032345RE'
>>> sub[-12:-2]
'C000032345'
>>>
```

Comment: This is not split. it is slice :)

Comment: ya sorry but hope it will work unless he is finding it in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use simple string splitting for this?

```
sub = "SW: C000032345RE"
sub[4:]
```

Or you can do:

```
sub.split(':')[1].strip()
```

Comment: `"ABCDSW: C000032345RE"`, If the string like this ?, and he not required `RE` also. And finally it's not spiting, It's slicing .

Comment: sub.split(':')[1].strip()